# API function decimal set not working

Tags: javascript, api

I've made a script, If a number starts with a 0, give that number a max of 6 decimals. If not (number starts with 1,2,3...), give that number a max of 2 decimals.

The script it works for numbers that doesn't start with a 0, numbers that do start with a 0 give back $0.000000. It doesn't show the actual price.

I've checked the API source and it actually display the correct price not the $0.000000 price.

an example number that does not work is : 0.328759

You can try it by changing

```
if (data[i].id == "bicoin")
```

too

```
if (data[i].id == "ripple") 
if (data[i].id == "kin")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>     
    $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == "bitcoin") {
        
    var num = data[i].price_usd;
    var str = num.toString();
    var firstnumb = str.charAt(0);
        if (firstnumb === "0") {
           // alert("6 Decimals");
            var numdecimal = parseInt(num, 10).toFixed(6);
            $("#priceusd").html("$" + numdecimal);
        } else {
          //  alert("2 Decimals");
            var numdecimal = parseInt(num, 10).toFixed(2);
            $("#priceusd").html("$" + numdecimal);
        } 
        }
  }
});      
    </script>
    

<span id ="priceusd"></span>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: well Integers does not have decimal points so it is not a surprise it would not work. You should be using parseFloat() or Number....

Comment: Thanks for the answers, not sure why I get downvotes. Someone please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`, if the number is less than 1 (starting with 0), `parseInt().toFixed()` will just return a few zeros

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>     
    $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == "ripple") {
        
    var num = data[i].price_usd;
    var str = num.toString();
    var firstnumb = str.charAt(0);
        if (firstnumb === "0") {
           // alert("6 Decimals");
            var numdecimal = parseFloat(num, 10).toFixed(6);
            $("#priceusd").html("$" + numdecimal);
        } else {
          //  alert("2 Decimals");
            var numdecimal = parseFloat(num, 10).toFixed(2);
            $("#priceusd").html("$" + numdecimal);
        } 
        }
  }
});      
    </script>
    

<span id ="priceusd"></span>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` will return an `int`.  If it starts with a `0.`, it will always return `0`.  You should be using `parseFloat`